# How to have a conditional class inside of input helper in Emberjs

Tags: html, ember.js

If I've got `{{input class="criteraInput" value=searchCriteria}}`, how can I can have a conditional class?

If it was normal HTML I would `<input class="{{if myProp 'active'}}/>` but I can't do that here.

Comment: did you try something like `myCssClass: function() { //your condition here, return "criteriaInput" or smth else }` in your controller/component and `{{input class=myCssClass value=searchCriteria}}`

Comment: There are other classes on the element though. I guess I could hardcode those in the JS but that seems hacky.

Comment: also ember adds classes `ember-view ember-text-field search-classes` so that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a conditional class, you could add a property to your controller and use that property. The conditional would have to be inside the controller's property.

```
{{input class=myControllerProp value=searchCriteria}}
```

It will append the classes passed like this to the `ember-view ember-text-field` classes.